# Invocar una llamada HTTP desde una aplicación Java

Tags: java, post, http, url, get

Estoy intentando programar una llamada HTTP desde una aplicación Java. La llamada se hace a una API que podría llevarse a cabo mediante API REST (cosa que ya he conseguido) pero me interesa saber como replicar ésta llamada usando el protocolo HTTP.
La estructura de la petición HTTP es esta:

```
GET /api/v1/real_time/analytics/raw_pose_data?date=2018-12-12&amp; 
building_id=1122 HTTP/1.1
Host: dashboard.situm.es
X-API-KEY: myApiKey
X-API-EMAIL: myEmail@mail.com
cache-control: no-cache
```

En mi código Java sé cómo realizar la conexión pero no consigo añadir los diferentes parámetros de la petición. Por ahora tengo algo así:

```
String url = "http://dashboard.situm.es";

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

// optional default is GET
con.setRequestMethod("GET");

//add request header
con.setRequestProperty("cache-control", "no-cache");

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

//print result
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

¿Como puedo pasar los parámetros de "/api/v1/real_time/analytics/raw_pose_data?date=2018-12-12& building_id=1122 HTTP/1.1", "X-API-KEY" y "X-API-EMAIL"? ¿Lo puedo hacer con la librería "java.io.*" o necesito otra?

Comment: Añadelos a la url - String url = "http://dashboard.situm.es/api/v1/real_time/analytics/raw_pose_data?date=2018-12-12&building_id=1122";

Comment: Gracias Evgeni.. si no estoy muy confundido (no acostumbro a programar web) el date y el building_id sería parámetros mientras que  "X-API-KEY" y "X-API-EMAIL" son headers? Como inserto headers en la petición?

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se intenta hacer una petición HTTP hay que diferenciar entre lo que son los headers y lo que son los parámetros. Lo parámetros son identificadores para especificar el recurso al que se quiere acceder y van incrustados en la URL (www.url.com/path?param1=x&param2=y)
Sin embargo, los headers se añaden mediante propiedades de la petición. Sobre la propia conexión se pueden añadir headers.

El código antetrios bien escrito sería (con.setRequestProperty() => añade headers):

```
String url = "https://dashboard.situm.es/api/v1/real_time/analytics/raw_pose_data?date=2018-12-12&building_id=1122";

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

// optional default is GET
con.setRequestMethod("GET");

//add request header
con.setRequestProperty("cache-control", "no-cache");
con.setRequestProperty("X-API-KEY", "myApiKey");
con.setRequestProperty("X-API-EMAIL", "myEmail@mail.com");

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

//print result
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Espero les sirva de ayuda.
;)